# Using navigator. mediaDevices. getUserMedia in vue3. js does not display streams

Tags: vuejs3, webrtc

I need to call the camera in vue3.js and put it in the

```
<video width="500px" height="500px" autoplay ref="myVid"></video>t
```

ag
It does not report errors in the console, but it also does not display streams

```
<template>
<video width="500px" height="500px" autoplay ref="myVid"></video>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted(){
    this.getneiname()
  },
  methods:{
    getneiname(){
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video:true
      })
      .then(stream=>{
          console.log("开启摄像头成功")
          this.$refs.myVid.srcobject  = stream
          this.$refs.myVid.play()
      }).catch(()=>{
        console.log("开启摄像头失败")
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried many methods, but they didn't work